# Search of files by means of keywords with a formatted output in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

Search of files by means of keywords with a formatted output

I'd like to find any kind of file by means of keywords and a formatted output, so I'm trying to use the command "`awk`, but I receive this error message:

```
% find . -type f -exec grep -if /home/peppespe/Documents/1265/keywords.txt  '{}' ';' -exec ls -laith '{}' ';' -exec md5sum '{}' | awk '{ print "md5 = " $1 }'  ';' -exec sha1sum '{}' | awk '{ print "sha1 = " $1 }' ';'
find: manca l'argomento per «-exec»
awk: linea progr.:1: fatale: non riesco ad aprire file `;' in lettura (File o directory non esistente)
awk: linea progr.:1: fatale: non riesco ad aprire file `;' in lettura (File o directory non esistente)
```

Comment: Please set your locale to en_US. Italian is hard to read for the most of us :)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use pipes in the argument to -exec, but they're parsed by the shell prior to calling find.  The result is that you're calling awk with ';' as an argument (and it thinks that's a file to open).

Rather than a long chain of -exec, you might want to output a list of files from grep and proceed from there. Something like this (untested)

```
grep -rifl keywords.txt | while read x; do
    echo "$x md5=$(md5sum $x) sha1=$(sha1sum $x)"
done
```

That's a bit different formatting from what you're doing, but maybe you can work with it from there. :-)